# In statistics why we always deal with random variables only?

Tags: distributions, random-variable

Actually I am not that good in statistics sometimes silly question like this arises in my mind So, if anyone could help me with the simple as well as complicated answer are welcome..(pardon me  if this question is not worth of )

Comment: The word "random" appears because the outcome is unknown before it happens. For instance, if we are talking about height, we will not be able to predict the exact values of the height of the individuals in a sample of 20 subjects before we measure them (although we can know beforehand that there are values that are more likely than others). The word "variable" appears because the outcome can assume different values in its domain (i.e., we are not dealing with constants).

Comment: This is probably because of the kind of statistics you have followed. In more advanced courses you will probably see random elements other than random variables (like in nonparametric statistics)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/264101#264101